# How to get value XML blob type in PLSQL?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have data XML format like this.

```
<"id=1">
   <"a">Test<"/a">
   <"b">Test2<"/b">
   <"c">Test3<"/c">
```

How to get value C in field XMLData?

```
*value C is Test3
```

Comment: Your data is not valid XML

Comment: What is a "XML blob type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get value C in field XMLData?

As mentioned by @Wernfried Domscheit  your `xml` doesnot look correct. See below one way to do it:

```
create table traptabclob(testclob clob);
/

insert into traptabclob 
values
('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DCResponse>
 <id>
   <Field key="a">Test</Field>
   <Field key="b">Test2</Field>
   <Field key="c">Test3</Field> 
  </id>                            
</DCResponse>');
/
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(testclob), '/DCResponse/id/Field[@key="c"]') col1
FROM traptabclob;
```

Output:

```
Col1
----
Test3
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d439f/2)

**Edit:**

> Thank you for your reply, my data doesn't has tag `<?xml> version="1.0"....` my data just like `<row> id="1"><a>Test</a><b>Test2</b></row>`, it is looks like `xml` type but i dont know this is `xml` type or not. Thank you

Please see that i have just given an example of valid xml file which contains usually `<?xml> version="1.0"....`. However issue with your xml code is putting tags in `"`. See below how it works:

```
create table traptabclob(testclob clob);
insert into traptabclob values('
 <id>
   <a>Test</a>
   <b>Test2</b>
   <c>Test3</c> 
  </id>');
```

Query:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(testclob), '/id/c') col1 
FROM traptabclob ;
```

Output:

```
Col1
----
Test3
```

[DEMO 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9289/1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
my data doesn't has tag <?xml version="1.0".... 
my data just like <row id="1"><a>Test</a><b>Test2</b></row>, it is looks like xml type but i dont know this is xml type or not.

Thank you

Comment: i've tried SELECT 
EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(testclob), '/ROW/c2') col1
FROM traptabclob in sqlfiddle, it's works but when i tried at sql developer it doesnt work

Comment: @aldiyudha Can you edit your question and put what you tried ?

Comment: thank you for your replied, it works but i didn't use xmltype function, because my data already xmltype